# Get detailed HTTP Response in C#

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm using Selenium to do some auto tests for my websites. if one of the websites or one of the pages in a website is down, i need get the Error code and description saved in a file.
I succeeded in using StatusCode and StatusDescription but they are both giving me the same vague output. For ex, a 404 error gives: Protocol Error. 
Below is my code. Any ideas?

```
    public static void GetPage(String url)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Report.txt", true);
        String result;
        try
        {
            // Creates an HttpWebRequest for the specified URL. 
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            if (myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                file.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and StatusDescription is: {0}", myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription);
            }
            else file.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is NOT OK and StatusDescription is: {0}", myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode);

            result = myHttpWebResponse.StatusDescription;

          //  HttpListenerResponse response1 = response;

            // Releases the resources of the response.
            myHttpWebResponse.Close();
            file.Close();
        }

        catch (WebException e)
        {

            file.WriteLine("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occurrrrrrrrrrred : {0}", e.Status);
            file.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            file.WriteLine("\nThe following Exception was raised : {0}", e.Message);
            file.Close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, Did you change anything in the code?

Answer (score 0):

`myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode` is an enumeration where the values of the members match the HTTP status codes, e.g.

```
public enum HttpStatusCode
{
    ...
    OK = 200
    Moved Permanently= 301,
    Moved Temporarily= 302,
    Forbidden= 403,
    ...
}
```

you can get the error code by accessing `(int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode` 

**HOWEVER**
you also have to check whether the response failed because of an server error (the WebException provides a WebResponse) or not.

Change your WebException catch loop to the following:

```
catch (WebException e)
        {
   if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
          {
                file.WriteLine("\r\nWebException Raised. The following error occurrrrrrrrrrred : {0}", (int)myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode);              
          }
    else
          {
                file.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Status);
          }
    file.Close();
        }
```